# wiquery-plugins integration with wicket 1.3.6 and maven repository

Tags: java, wicket

I am using wicket-1.3.6, can I use wiquery plugin in my application?

What is the maven repository for wiquery plugin?

Thanks and Regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maven information:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.wiquery-plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>wiquery-plugins</artifactId>
    <version>1.1</version>
</dependency>

<repositories>
   <repository>
     <id>wiquery plugin repository</id>
     <name>wiQuery plugin repository</name>
     <url>http://wiquery-plugins.googlecode.com/svn/m2repo/</url>
     <layout>default</layout>
   </repository>
</repositories>
```

I have no idea of the support for this in jquery/wicket.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it can't be. I think there were some incompatible api changes in wicket 1.4

Comment: thanks. I want to use tooltip which is available in wiquery plugin (org.wiquery.plugin.jquertytools.tooltip.TooltipBehavior). I guess it is not in wiquery core. That is why I mentioned wiquery plugin in my question. As I found the core repo before.

Comment: @Tapas Bose I have updated my answer, sorry I missed the plugin part, I have not tested that this is correct, but you can give it a go

Comment: thanks. But It seems wiquery-plugin will not work with wicket 1.3.6. wiquery-plugin is dependent on wiquery-core. I have added wiquery-core 1.1 jar. But on deployment I am getting exception java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.wicket.MetaDataKey: method <init>()V not found
 at org.odlabs.wiquery.core.commons.WiQueryInitializer$1.<init>(WiQueryInitializer.java:42)

Comment: @Tapas Bose Then it can't be used :(